# Select query runs slow

Tags: postgresql, select, insert, postgis

I have a postgres (postgis) select query from multiple tables that I want to insert in a result table. The problem is that it takes around 2 seconds per selection, and it has to do around two million selections, which leaves me with a month long process.

The thing is that in the same script I have very similar Select queries that take 0.3 seconds. The result table doesn't have any indexes that may slow it down, and the other select queries use the same tables, so I don't know why this one is taking so long. I have tested it and it runs equally slow regardless of the row it is processing, so it's not an input problem, but the query itself, or at least that's my guess.

This is the slow query:

```
INSERT INTO result(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, Yutm, Xutm, Y, X, geom, distancia, v) 
SELECT '{0}', m.b, r.nom_, c.id, l.tipo, d.distr, s.tipn, p.secc, 
       ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,32613)), 
       ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,32613)), 
       ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,4326)), 
       ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,4326)),
       p.geom, 
       ST_DISTANCE(p.geom,v.geom), v.cat 
FROM r, m,  l,  c, d, s, v,  p 
WHERE p.estado = '{0}' 
  AND left(m.b, 2) = '{0}' 
  AND p.id5 = '{1}' 
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, m.geom) 
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, l.geom) 
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, c.geom) 
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, d.geom) 
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, s.geom) 
  AND ST_DWithin(p.geom, v.geom, 0.000524) 
Order by p.id5, st_distance(p.geom,v.geom) 
limit 1
```

This is the EXPLAIN for that query:

```
Insert on result  (cost=49452.92..49452.97 rows=1 width=334) (actual time=1804.548..1804.548 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=49452.92..49452.97 rows=1 width=334) (actual time=1803.256..1803.257 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Limit  (cost=49452.92..49452.92 rows=1 width=497) (actual time=1803.217..1803.217 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=49452.92..49454.20 rows=511 width=497) (actual time=1803.217..1803.217 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: (st_distance(p.geom, v.geom))
                    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=15.37..49450.36 rows=511 width=497) (actual time=40.160..1803.105 rows=32 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.04..49211.22 rows=3 width=486) (actual time=39.800..1799.749 rows=32 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: ((p.geom && c.geom) AND _st_intersects(p.geom, c.geom))"
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3222464
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.04..10687.66 rows=1 width=433) (actual time=5.510..326.752 rows=32 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..9623.19 rows=1 width=207) (actual time=5.450..324.692 rows=32 loops=1)
                                            Join Filter: ((p.geom && l.geom) AND _st_intersects(p.geom, l.geom))
                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 752544
                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..129.53 rows=1 width=181) (actual time=0.269..5.447 rows=32 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..121.10 rows=1 width=162) (actual time=0.148..2.622 rows=32 loops=1)
                                                        Join Filter: ((p.geom && d.geom) AND _st_intersects(p.geom, d.geom))
                                                        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 64
                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..94.63 rows=32 width=154) (actual time=0.018..0.074 rows=32 loops=1)
                                                              ->  Index Scan using id5_index_index on  p  (cost=0.56..92.99 rows=1 width=122) (actual time=0.013..0.030 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                    Index Cond: (id5 = 10)
                                                                    Filter: ((estado)::text = '01'::text)
                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 30
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on r  (cost=0.00..1.32 rows=32 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.014 rows=32 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=3 width=40) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=3 loops=32)
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on  d  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=40) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Index Scan using m_bue_geom_gist on m  (cost=0.14..8.42 rows=1 width=14077) (actual time=0.085..0.086 rows=1 loops=32)
                                                        Index Cond: (p.geom && geom)
                                                        Filter: (("left((b)::text, 2) = '01'::text) AND _st_intersects(p.geom, geom))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                            ->  Seq Scan on  l  (cost=0.00..3320.18 rows=23518 width=1007) (actual time=0.001..2.878 rows=23518 loops=32)
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on v  (cost=10.33..1064.46 rows=1 width=226) (actual time=0.052..0.060 rows=1 loops=32)
                                            Recheck Cond: (geom && st_expand(p.geom, '0.000524'::double precision))
                                            Filter: ((p.geom && st_expand(geom, '0.000524'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(p.geom, geom, '0.000524'::double precision))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=64
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on v_geom_gist  (cost=0.00..10.33 rows=255 width=0) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=3 loops=32)
                                                  Index Cond: (geom && st_expand(p.geom, '0.000524'::double precision))
                                ->  Seq Scan on  c  (cost=0.00..12089.03 rows=100703 width=762) (actual time=0.004..20.435 rows=100703 loops=32)
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on s  (cost=4.33..33.70 rows=2 width=2046) (actual time=0.072..0.081 rows=1 loops=32)
                                Recheck Cond: (p.geom && geom)
                                Filter: _st_intersects(p.geom, geom)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                Heap Blocks: exact=96
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on s_geom_gist  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=3 loops=32)
                                      Index Cond: (p.geom && geom)
Planning time: 6.801 ms
Execution time: 1804.740 ms
```

I don´t have much experience with postgres and query optimization, so my hands are tied. How do you guys think I can make this query faster?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks to be a PostGIS query. Consider tagging for the very specialized extension of Postgres.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the index definitions (`CREATE INDEX ..`) for `v_geom_gist`, `m_bue_geom_gist` and `id5_index_index`. It's hard to tell from your obfuscated table and column names, but a similar index on `c` might help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing a lot of calculations and then based on those calculations you are looking to find the smallest one based on parameters

A lot of these calculations can be performed before hand and stored in the table.  Then the query is just a filter (and I expect easy to make an index on the criteria.)

so if we look at the following fields

```
ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,32613)), 
ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,32613)), 
ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,4326)), 
ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(p.geom,4326)),
ST_DISTANCE(p.geom,v.geom)
ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, m.geom) 
ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, l.geom) 
ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, c.geom) 
ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, d.geom) 
ST_INTERSECTS(p.geom, s.geom) 
ST_DWithin(p.geom, v.geom, 0.000524) 
st_distance(p.geom,v.geom)
```

If you create a new table with these values that can be linked in or add it to one of your existing tables your insert queries will be much faster.